# How can I add a new Facet from the beginning in IBM WCA (IBM Watson)?

Tags: ibm-watson

right now I created a new Facet but it is not being shown in the Portal, I would like to know the steps to see if I forgot any steps or if I can create one from scratch. (I already have an account and I already have a collection)

Version: 3.5.0.4